# Why can't I offer a bounty on a question?

Tags: support, bounties

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369748/entity-framework-and-sql-server-synonyms) on 6 December, so surely I should be able to offer a bounty on it by now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an [existing open bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278452/equivalent-of-reference-copy-local-in-asp-net-web-site-project). Stack Exchange currently only allows 1 open bounty at a time.

Comment: Ah, good call.  This is the reason, @ProfK

Comment: Should this be added to the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/67392)?

Comment: Thanks @waiwai933, that would never have crossed my mind.  Is this new?